What minimum size tank is suitable for coral?
I was told that you can keep them in just about any tank but am somewhat skeptical. Can I really keep coral in a small tank? Or do I need a big fishtank?
TL;DR What size aquarium (gallon/liters) is the minimum suitable for coral? Can I put coral into any size tank?

I doubt coral cares about tank size directly. Water chemistry and temperature is much more likely to be a concern. Remember that coral is an animal, which means you need to understand what your variety will eat and not filter that out of the water.
